# Keychain - Touch ID request loop

Tags: mac, keychain, touch-id

I've bought the latest MacBook Pro with Touch bar. I've installed clean installation of Mac OSX (latest, no updates avail.). Whenever I open keychain, the Touch ID request dialog is shown. After using Touch ID the dialog is shown after few seconds. Multiple entry (like 20) didn't help. Even if I close the Mac and use external monitor, Touch ID dialog is shown.

Any advice?
Thank you,
Martin

Comment: FYI I've found that you can also hit [Esc], or cancel the dialog with no ill effects.